# Javascript Library for 2d CAD with Intersections and Fillet

Tags: javascript, three.js, cad, openjscad

I'm looking for a javascript library that does 2D computer aided design. Main features I'm looking for are:

1. Generalized parametric curves
2. Finding the closest points on 2 non-intersecting curves
3. Intersections of 2 curves.
4. Possible to create Polylines
5. Fillet

Is there any such library and do you possibly have a sample code?